# Hiding the Back Button on a TabbedBarController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've a NavigationViewController which segues to a TabbedBarController. I don't want to show the back button on the TabbedBarController.
I've tried both these code snippets in Swift , neither works,

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }
```

Here's a snap shot,

Here's the tabbed bar view controller,

How can I hide the back button on the Tabbed bar view controller. How can I hide the back button on my tabbed bar controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite many ways to do what you want, but what I'm 99.9% sure that would work is that you can add a barButton in your leftBarButtonItems to replace the default backButton of your navigationController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)]
}
```

Also, when overriding any lifecycle methods of a controller, you might not want to miss anything from the parent class, so don't forget to call its super equivalent like `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`

I hope this helps!

EDIT: Two ways to do what you want in tabBarController and since I can already picture the flow of your project.

1. Put the code inside the `viewWillAppear` of your tabBarController. This means that you might need to subclass the `UITabBarController`. So it should be like this:

   ```
   class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
       override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           super.viewWillAppear(animated)

           self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)]
       }
   }
   ```
2. You should present modally your tabBarController (this is more ideal).

Comment: So this removes the back button from the PreviousViewController which is segueing into the tabbed bar controller. I want to remove the back button from the TabbedBarViewController.

Comment: ```I've a NavigationViewController which segues to a TabbedBarController. I don't want to show the back button on the TabbedBarController.``` <--- In my answer, I am removing the back button of the TabbedBarController. This is exactly what you want! Have you tried it though? Attaching a screenshot of what you want helps.

Comment: So I've ViewController A which is embedded into a NavigationController which segues into B which segues into a tabbed bar controller which has C and D. I added your code to B and it lost the back button. What I want is C and D to lose the back buttons.

Comment: Do you have time to upload a screenshot of your current result? Because I can't seem to get what you're getting. Removing or hiding the backButton of the tabBarController embedded in a navigationController of ViewController A means the C and D does not backButtons too, assuming that your way of embedding each controllers in a navigationController is correct..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181787/discussion-between-melissa-stewart-and-glenn).